# Импорт GitHub issues в Eclipse

Tags: github, eclipse

Никак не могу разобраться как импортировать (синхронизировать) issues из репозитория. Вроде всё настроил, создавать Task'и в Eclips'е могу (они добавляются в GitHub), а как получить уже имеющиеся issues из репозитория?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Task List жмём правую кнопку мыши: New -> Query
[image: Контекстное меню]
В появившемся окне выбираем или добавляем Task Repository
[image: Выбираем репозиторий]
Жмём Next.
Заполняем, Finish.
[image: Вводим название]

Comment: Что значит: не является ответом на вопрос? Я спросил. Методом тыка нашёл ответ и ответил. В TaskList правой кнопкой мыши вызвал контекстное меню, в нём выбрал New -> Query. В Eclipse импортировались все issues.

Comment: Ваша правда. Только оформите ответ должным образом(распишите, как вы справились с проблемой, которая изложена в вопросе), чтобы это было понятно тем, кто придет сюда за ответом.